# Why wont this resize of iframe height work?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a form on my main page (main.html) with the target set to an iframe on that page. The action of the frame on the main page is a php file.
So, the php file displays in the iframe basically.

Now, I have this script in the php file to get height of content:

```
var x = document.body.scrollHeight;
window.parent.document.getelementbyid("iframe001").style.height=x;
```

If I alert x, the scrollheight is there, so x IS the scrollheight definetely. That part works.
But, I cant set that value to the height of the iframe (iframe001).

Any ideas why I cant do this? And how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getelementbyid should be getElementById

also this answer might help you [dynamic iframe height depending on PHP content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815129/dynamic-iframe-height-depending-on-php-content/1815166#1815166)